# XCode beta 15 React-Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Undefined symbols:

```
System:
  OS: macOS 14.0
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
  Memory: 299.64 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.14.0
    path: /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.11
    path: /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.3.1
    path: /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.08.14.00
    path: /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.4
      - iOS 16.4
      - macOS 13.3
      - tvOS 16.4
      - watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
  Xcode:
    version: 14.3.1/14E300c
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 11.0.18
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.71.10
    wanted: 0.71.10
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false`
```

```js
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React-Core.common-AccessibilityResources"
        target.remove_from_project
      end

      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
      end
    end
```